# How to remove the list of dictionary elements with the same specific key-value

Tags: python

I want my python code to browse the list elements and remove those whose 'time' values are the same while keeping the first ones.
Here is my list:

```
a = [
     {'time': '18.00', 'id': 'bus_1', 'CO2': '8165.28'},
     {'time': '20.00', 'id': 'bus_1' , 'CO2': '0.00'},
     {'time': '21.00', 'id': 'f2.0' , 'CO2': '0.00'},
     {'time': '18.00', 'id': 'bus_1', 'CO2': '8165.28', 'waiting': '0.00'},
     {'time': '20.00', 'id': 'bus_1', 'CO2': '0.00', 'waiting': '0.00'}
     ]
```

The expected output:

```
b = [
     {'time': '18.00', 'id': 'bus_1', 'CO2': '8165.28'},
     {'time': '20.00', 'id': 'bus_1' , 'CO2': '0.00'},
     {'time': '21.00', 'id': 'f2.0' , 'CO2': '0.00'},
    ]
```

Comment: Please include what you've tried to solve it, too.

Comment: Iterate over `a` keeping a `set` of previously seen time values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to keep track of time already seen:

```py
a = [
     {'time': '18.00', 'id': 'bus_1', 'CO2': '8165.28'},
     {'time': '20.00', 'id': 'bus_1' , 'CO2': '0.00'},
     {'time': '21.00', 'id': 'f2.0' , 'CO2': '0.00'},
     {'time': '18.00', 'id': 'bus_1', 'CO2': '8165.28', 'waiting': '0.00'},
     {'time': '20.00', 'id': 'bus_1', 'CO2': '0.00', 'waiting': '0.00'}
     ]

output, time_seen = [], set()
for dct in a:
    time = dct['time']
    if time not in time_seen:
        output.append(dct)
        time_seen.add(time)

print(output)
# [{'time': '18.00', 'id': 'bus_1', 'CO2': '8165.28'},
#  {'time': '20.00', 'id': 'bus_1', 'CO2': '0.00'},
#  {'time': '21.00', 'id': 'f2.0', 'CO2': '0.00'}]
```

Comment: Thank you, What if I want to remove the first two elements and keep the last three elements in the next round?